# Does a 'DISABLE TRIGGER ALL' also disable DOMAIN checks in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like just to confirm if the `'ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE TRIGGER ALL'` also disables `DOMAIN` checks in Postgres?

Comment: Not sure, they might be setup separately

Answer (score 1):

No, DOMAIN and CHECK constraints are not disabled.

Only some constraints are implemented as triggers in Postgres. The most notable would be a trigger on the "parent" table in the FK constraint, and triggers on deferrable unique / exclusion constraints. These require some complicated logic that cannot be checked against a single row and were, consequently, implemented as triggers.

DOMAIN checks are entirely "internal", the checks cannot use subqueries, and by all means operate like CHECK constraints. There should be no triggers.

You could check `pg_trigger` to see if your target table has any "internally defined' triggers.